# I want to develop a basic static content displaying Android app

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase-realtime-database, storage, mobile-development

What are the basic ways in which i can achieve it?

Comment: Is the data static - not changing ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest in a first approach and in order to be more dynamically store that information in a host(server), doing this you just need:

1)Request the data from the server using `REST` or `GRAPHQL`,etc.

2)Keep cached the necessary information in the app, thats need to be updated or resend to the server, using some `HTTP` strategies like `Itags` [Last Modified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Last-Modified)

Android had a powerfull channels to resolved that kind of doubts : https://youtu.be/GBeN74Xuk2M

Comment: Thanks.  I will Keep your suggestion in mind while building the app.